# Update query not working node js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to update the database using mysql in my node js app when i press a button however it is not executing. Can someone help me figure this out. Thank you

This is the code in the ejs file:

```
function Resolve(){

              $.ajax({
                  url: "/resolve-complaint",
                  type: "post",
                  dataType: "json",
                  data: { "Id": "14" },
                  success: function (data) {
                      if(data.status=="success"){
                          alert(" has been resolved.");
                      }
                  }
              });
          }
```

This is the code in the index.js file:

```
router.post('/resolve-complaint', function (req, res, next) {

pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {

    connection.query('update complaint set resolved=1 where cid='+req.body.Id, function (err, rows) {
        connection.release();

    });

});
res.json({ "status": "success" });
```

});

Comment: Not executing? How far does the code execute? Try setting some breakpoints / console.log's or try testing the server on its own with curl: `curl -XPOST http://localhost:3000/resolve-complaint --header "Content-type:application/json" -d "{\"Id\": 14}`

Comment: I get the alert box when i press the button however when i check the database i don't find theupdate

Answer (score 0):

Always check your `err` parameter. You most likely have your answer there.

Depending on the situation, it's usually a good idea to do something like this:

```
... function (err, rows) {
    if (err) return console.error(err); // <---
    connection.release();
});
```

or, maybe more approperite in your case:

```
... function (err, rows) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.send({ "status": "failure" });
    }
    connection.release();
});
```

That should be done for both `pool.getConnection` and `connection.query`.

Also, you send the success message before you know if it was successful or not. You should try sending the success message in the callback.

Comment: Where should i add this? I am new to this and I am still learning.

Comment: In both your callback functions that got an `err` parameter. (ie the line after `pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {` and `connection.query('update complaint set resolved=1 where cid='+req.body.Id, function (err, rows) {`.

You might be used to more traditional languages that throw an exception when something goes wrong, here you have do error checking manually and decide what to do on a case by case basis.

Comment: I added function(err, rows) however I didn't get any error. Is there a tutorial for all of this? I really don't know what to search for since I started learning from my friend's code so i don't know where to start. Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure about any tutorials, but there should be plenty.  This would probably be covered in any tutorial handling node basics.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I just meant that you should add the if statement. Basically if there is an error: log it and respond with failure